# dynamic structure declaration

Tags: c

I have a some pieces of code in my project in which a structure z is being used. This structure declaration changes as per a condition flag being set in my system. I want the structure declaration to be dynamic.

if condition flag is 0 then,

```
struct x z;
```

if condition flag is 1 then,

```
struct y z;
```

but the operation to be performed on z would be the same. Currently this is handled by declaring both the structure :

```
struct x z_x;
struct y z_y;
```

then as per the condition flag use the appropriate structure in the code. This method doesn't seem to be optimal. Any suggestions on handling this type of code ?

Comment: What is this condition flag, a macro, known compile time?

Comment: This condition flag  is determined runtime.

Comment: What you want to achieve - to use less memory or just to have only one variable, not to check that flag each time? For the second - I can't think of a way to avoid this.

Comment: Basically to reduce the text size. Currently i need to repeat the operations with both the structures ; leads to repetitive coding. I want to avoid repetitive coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the flag is run-time, you cannot avoid checking this flag all the time. At least, I can't think of such way.

But you still can reduce the memory and the code. I'd do it like this:

---

To reduce the memory usage:

```
struct z_x* = NULL;
struct z_y* = NULL;

//...

if( flag )
{
    z_x = malloc( sizeof( struct x ) );
}
else
{
    z_y = malloc( sizeof( struct y ) );
}
```

---

To reduce the code, instead of writing all the time things like:

```
if( flag )
{
    // do operations_N with z_x
}
else
{
    // do operations_N with z_y
}
```

I'd write:

```
operations_N( z_x, z_y, flag );
```

where

```
void operations_N( struct x* z_x, struct y* z_y, flag )
{
    if( flag )
    {
        // do operations_N with z_x
    }
    else
    {
        // do operations_N with z_y
    }
}
```

of course, `operations_1` and `flag` should have some good and logical names.

BUT this could lead do some problems, so just be careful, if you decide to use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use #ifdefs to create structure:

```
typedef struct
{
#ifdef MY_FLAG
int s;
#else
float s;
#endif
} z;
```

You can also use union, the structure will have both fields at the same time and you will use the one you need.

```
union {
int i;
float f;
} z;
```

z.i = 1;
z.f = 1.0;

This way you should use only one member at a time.